Why can't nasm write / in unicode?
Trying to run the following
section .text
   global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc
    
_start:                  ;tell linker entry point
   ;create the file
   mov  eax, 8
   mov  ebx, file_name
   mov  ecx, 0777        ;read, write and execute by all
   int  0x80             ;call kernel
    
   mov [fd_out], eax
    
   ; write into the file
   mov  edx, len         ;number of bytes
   mov  ecx, msg         ;message to write
   mov  ebx, [fd_out]    ;file descriptor 
   mov  eax,4            ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80             ;call kernel

   ; close the file
   mov eax, 6
   mov ebx, [fd_out]
    
   ; write the message indicating end of file write
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, msg_done
   mov edx, len_done
   int  0x80
    
   ;open the file for reading
   mov eax, 5
   mov ebx, file_name
   mov ecx, 0             ;for read only access
   mov edx, 0777          ;read, write and execute by all
   int  0x80
    
   mov  [fd_in], eax
    
   ; read from file
   mov eax, 3
   mov ebx, [fd_in]
   mov ecx, info
   mov edx, len
   int 0x80
    
   ; close the file
   mov eax, 6
   mov ebx, [fd_in]
   int  0x80    
    
   ; print the info 
   mov eax, 4
   mov ebx, 1
   mov ecx, info
   mov edx, len
   int 0x80
       
   mov  eax,1             ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80              ;call kernel

section .data
file_name db 'myfile.txt'
msg db `\u002f`
len equ  $-msg

msg_done db 'Written to file', 0xa
len_done equ $-msg_done

section .bss
fd_out resb 1
fd_in  resb 1
info resb  26

But standard unicode forward slash won't work. The output is blank
Other unicode characters work fine. For example
section .data
file_name db 'myfile.txt'
msg db `\u002c` ; comma ,
len equ  $-msg


section .data
file_name db 'myfile.txt'
msg db `\u0040` ; at sign @
len equ  $-msg

also tried

msg db 0x2f,0xa

msg db 0x2f

msg db 0x2f,0

msg db 2fh

Tried everything from
https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.03/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2
Other unicode slashes work, just not the default 002F

Your file_name is missing the terminating zero hence will be concatenated with the msg and if that's a slash that makes it invalid (and in other cases it would append it to the file name which is still not what you want). You do not have any error checking otherwise you would have seen that the open fails. Also strace and gdb are your friends. Has nothing to do with unicode.

To fix this change from file_name db 'myfile.txt' to file_name db 'myfile.txt', 0
